# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Controller::getProductUrl()

Tags: magento-1.9, product, url

once we click on **button** in product view page, we are creating **New Product Programatically** & now i am trying to redirect to Newly created Product's url after click on same button.

**Error** :

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined method Amasty_Example_AmastyController::getProductUrl() in line :

```
$result['redirect'] = $product->getProductUrl();
```

> code

```
public function createSimpleProductAndRedirectAction() 
{ 

$originalProductId = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id"); 
$originalProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($originalProductId); 


      if ($product = $this->_createProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE, true, $originalProduct))
         { 
            if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) 
                { 
                   $result['redirect'] = $product->getProductUrl(); 
                   $result['message'] = "Your Image Saved"; 
                   return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result)); 
                } 
         } 
}

protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct, $newImagePath = "")
    {

        try {
            if (isset($login) && (is_array($login) && !empty($login)) || ($login != "")) {

                $result['redirect'] = $this->_getRefererUrl() ? $this->_getRefererUrl() : Mage::getUrl('customer/account', array(
                    '_secure' => true
                ));
                $result['success'] = true;          

                $customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();               

                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                return $this;
            } else {
                $customerId = "";

            }

            if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
                $res = $this->saveProduct($type, $doSave, $originalProduct, $newImagePath);
                $result['success'] = true;
                $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                return $this; exit;
            } else {

            }

        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {}

        } catch (Exception $e) { }              
    }

public function saveProduct($type, $doSave = true, $originalProduct) 
{

            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $rand = rand(11, 999999999);
            $product->setUrlKey($rand);


            $product->setName($originalProduct->getName());        
            $product->save();   

            return $product;
}
```

**js**

```
_ajaxCreateImg: function(dataUrl, startNumber) 
{ 
    new Ajax.Request(this.createImgUrl, { 
        onComplete: function(response) { 
            var responseData = response.responseText.evalJSON(); 
            if(lastRequest == 1){ 
                this._processAjaxResponse(response); 
                window.location.replace(responseData.redirect); 
            } 
         }.bind(this) 
     }); 
},
```

Comment: check if `$product` is really product object - maybe variable holds something else, or you product hasn't been loaded.

Comment: @lord_of_strings i guess product is not loaded..... because we are calling the code : `$result['redirect'] = $product->getProductUrl();` before creation of product,  means in this function : `createSimpleProductAndRedirectAction` but product is created in this function : `saveProduct`.... can you please help where i need to place the code ?

Comment: You have to review your code, as in `_createProduct` in `try` block different objects can be returned. Make sure you return product. By the way, some refactoring would be nice, because every method get a lot of arguments which is not desired. Try to make them use 1-2, and use more class variables, to make it all more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `_createProduct` does not return an instance of a product model. It returns `$this` which is an instance of the current controller.
Make sure it returns the product you just created.